# Trying to access the end point of a json rpc service from a java spring API by using axios in react js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, cors, json-rpc

I'm actually trying to access the method at that endpoint but I keep getting the classic CORS error
***"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/rpc-measurements' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."***

```
@JsonRpcService("rpc-measurements")
public interface JsonRpcAPI {

   public List<Measurements> getMeasurementsByDays(String username, int days);
   public Float getAvgEnergyConsumption();
   public String getUsername(String username);
}
```

The implementation:

```
@Service
@AutoJsonRpcServiceImpl
public class JsonRpcAPIimpl implements JsonRpcAPI {

@Autowired
private MeasurementsRepository measurementsRepository;
@Autowired
private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Override
public List<Measurements> getMeasurementsByDays(String username, int days) {
    Person person = personRepository.findByName(username);
    List<Device> devices = deviceRepository.findByPersonId(person.getId());
    List<Measurements> measurements = new ArrayList<>();
    devices.forEach(x -> {
          measurements.addAll(measurementsRepository.getEnergyConsumptionForDays(UuidAdapter.getBytesFromUUID(x.getId()), days));
    });
    return measurements;
}

@Override
public Float getAvgEnergyConsumption() {
    return 0.0f;
}

@Override
public String getUsername(String username) {
    return username;
}
}
```

The security configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Resource(name = "userService")
private CustomUserService userService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    /*http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();*/
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Autowired
private UnauthorizedEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint;

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}
}
```

And finally the react js function that calls the API:

```
function handleValueSelect(event) {
    axios.post(REST_API_URL + '/rpc-measurements', {
        id: "1",
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method:"getAvgEnergyConsumption",
        params:[]
    },{
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken')
        }
    }).then(res => {
        setDataP(res.data.map((data) => ({
            time: ((data.time.split('T')[1])
                .split('+')[0])
                .split('.')[0],
            value: data.value
        })));
    });
};
```

I have been wasting half a day trying to find some solutions, most of the problems related to the CORS policy error that I found on the internet were solved by either adding the @CrossOrigin annotation to a controller or by adding http.cors() in the security configuration file, the thing is that I am not trying to access an endpoint from a controller I am trying to access an endpoint from a json rpc service in order to use a method from there and I have no idea if I have to set up cross origin for that particular path in a different way compared to a controller (where you just use the annotation, and yes I already tried adding it to the service).

The weirdest thing is that I tried accessing the URL in postman with exactly the same body as in the axios request and it worked, but when I tried in the web client the CORS error kept popping up. I even tried creating a Rest Controller and using JsonRpcRestClient to invoke the method but it didn't work, it freezes my spring app, I don't even get an error or an exception in the console, it just stops responding.

So I wanted to ask if there's someone who's been in a similar situation or has some ideas on how to deal with the CORS policy error taking into account that I am trying to access an end point from a Service and not a controller.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue with react and spring.
In this case, browser is blocking your request.
put the reactjs build file inside template folder and run spring boot sends index.html then reactjs start works and cros error not come but it requires restController for all other requests.